# Does BLE support pinging?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is BLE supporting pinging, i.e. sending a message to other devices and receiving their status?

I want to write an app on Android, which will ping each of the nearby devices and calculate the time between sending time and receiving answer, is it possible?

Comment: not shure what you like to accomplish. You can scan for nerby devices and they even give you a RSSI value. Which can be used to calculate the distance

Comment: I don't want to use RSSI to calculate distance I want use time of Arrival(ToA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out in your comment you like to use as time-of-arrival or time-difference-of-arrival algorithm to calculate the distance based on bluetooth.

To my knowledge this is currently more a theoretical approach in a bluetooth environment. As radio signals travel at light speed (~29.979 cm in one nanosecond) you will need a high sampling resolution to get a accurate result. Each nanosecound deviation will cause an error of roughly 30 cm.

With WiFi this is accomplished with a specalized chipset. To my knowledge this is currently not possibile with android as it would need a lot of low level support (Chipset and OS)

Hope this helps!

here are some sources

- [Android relative positioning, Wifi:Time of Arrival](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325979/android-relative-positioning-wifitime-of-arrival)
- [Evaluation of indoor positioning based on
  Bluetooth Smart technology - page 76](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/199826/199826.pdf)

Comment: Of course it helps a lot.
So, my first plan failed. 
Is it possible to create an special beacon from android? Special, because with beacon signals, I want to add ID of signal, to enable nearby devices identify each signal.

Comment: This should be possibile. Have a look into the BLE GATT protocol, there are charachteristics (parameters) which you can read/write by other devices. You will need one device in peripheral mode and one in central mode. This should be a good start https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUbFB1Qypg8

Answer (score 0):

You can easily see the timestamp of discovery for each device in your onScanResult method:

```
@Override
public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result){

Long lastSeen = result.getTimestampNanos();
//rest of your code

}
```

See the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanResult.html). You can use this timestamp and the time that you started your scan to get an approximate response time for each device.